# Use MemoryCache as a fallback for DistributedCache

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-core, redis

My ASP.NET Core application uses a Redis instance for DistributedCache. I'm worried because sometimes we may have connection issues with Redis and our system may become some minutes without Cache and that will have a great negative impact for performance.

To minimize this problem and dependency with Redis, we would like to add the MemoryCache service to store data but ONLY when the Redis DistributedCache becomes unavailable, so I won't use the machine memory to duplicate data that is available in Redis if Redis is working fine.

**How can I use MemoryCache as a fallback for when DistributedCache is unavailable and ONLY when DistributedCache is unavailable?**

One option would be to add a middleware for MemoryCache and manually check if Redis is online by polling every 30 seconds. But this sounds horrible. I'm expecting that someone may have thought in a smarter solution for this based on ASP.NET Core configurations.

Comment: If there is a negative impact for when the Redis cache is offline, how would that impact be any different if you switch over to a different cache which is (at that time) still empty? And how do you plan to invalidate the cache even when you are (possibly) constantly switching the caches? I think this approach is a lot more complicated than you think it would be. Maybe you should look into Redis-specific fallback scenarios instead, so that your application does not have to implement this itself.

Comment: Wellcome to SO ) It`s probably a good idea to use in memory cache - and that in memory cache synchronize with the Redis data - if it is available. Memory cache update itself if not it serves the old data. There is drawback - different instances of the server might end up with the different cache state, syncing them is really painful - service fabric ever have Reliable Collection for that ...

Comment: @poke the memory cache will be empty in the first request, but will serve the results for the next hundreds of request until the Redis instance recover

Comment: @Vladimir I would prefer to avoid using MemoryCache when Redis is online to avoid using lots of CPU memory without needing. Redis stay online through days and days. The issue is during the few minutes in the month that it fails.

Comment: Actually it is RAM memory - not CPU, and it way to faster then any tcp network call to Redis (as Redis a TCP server solution),  unless Redis located at the same VM as a server (ideally via pipes ), and that`s not happen often )

Comment: Might use much less elegant solution then memory cache - have 2 Redis caches - and if one of then down - use other kind of back up Redis, and pinging Main server, as long as you get response from the main Redis - switch back to it. Requeres no RAM memory om server, but RAM in server ussually is not an issue.

Comment: @Vladimir as I see now, having 2 Redis caches (= Redis cluster) is the common solution, but this extra instance was not considered before and I can't afford a new machine for this right now.

Comment: then in memory cache is the best solution.

Comment: Distributed Memory Cache is surely designed for this? Despite the name, it's not distributed and just implements in-memory caching for the app instance, but the benefit is it has the same IDistributedCache interface. Intended for development/test and production environments when deployment doesn't need the distributed cache.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#distributed-memory-cache

Comment: Here is an article how to achieve this: https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/a-multilevel-cache-retrieval-design-for-net/